# Sharing a database shared from another account to a reader account in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I requested a dataset from snowflake marketplace which got created as a shared database in my account. Now from my account, I created a reader account. I wanted to share the shared database with the reader account by running the below. I knew it will not work, but wanted to take a chance:)

```
grant usage on database COVID19_EPIDEMIOLOGICAL_DATA to share reader_acct_share;
```

But my question is, if I want to share a shared database, is my only option to create another database from the share and then share it. In that case,I will also have to create a scheduled process to synchronize between the shared database and the database created from it. Is my understanding correct or is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shared databases and all the objects in the database cannot be forwarded (i.e. re-shared with other accounts).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers#general-limitations-for-shared-databases

The following actions are not supported:
Creating a clone of a shared database or any schemas/tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you are right , you can't share shared-database through share object to reader account, the approach is create new local database , materialize the objects such as tables into this new local database and create share out of this local database.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring my moral compass:

You might be able to use a [secure materialized view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-materialized-view) `select * from shared_with_me` and share the "secured view" as those are sharable.

But if this works, I would suggest it's a bug in the security model, that need fixing. If someone X shares with you Y, they have shared with you not Z. If X want Z they can share with them as well. Thus there is zero reason for you to reshare.

And it's a possible violation of so many GDPR like things.